# How do I resolve an "Unable to generate SSH keys for user" error when connecting to my Mac

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have a pretty vanilla setup with Windows 10 / Visual Studio 2017 Community and a Mac running Sierra with Visual Studio for Mac (2017?)

When I try to get Visual Studio to connect to the Mac through Tools->Options->Xamarin->iOS Settings->Find Xamarin Mac Agent, I get the following error message instead of a connection to the Mac.

> "Unable to generate SSH keys for user"

[image: Visual Studio Error Message when Setting up connection to Mac for Xamarin]

How can I resolve this error.

Answer (score 0):

This indicates to me that your User ID and password are correct, but you are not able to setup a proper SSH connection to your Mac. It's required for Visual Studio on the PC to talk to the Mac.

n.b., if your User appears as "John Smith" in the "Users & Groups" settings for the PC, your User ID will be "johnsmith" (no spaces).

If you open a terminal window and do the following:

```
ssh localhost
```

Try to login with your password.

It may give you some clues as to the error. In my particular case, it I had an empty .ssh file that had been created in my home directory and prevented the `authorized_keys` and `known_hosts` files from being created. The .ssh file should have been a directory (`chmod 700`).

Renaming/deleting the file was sufficient to make the localhost ssh work, and also the connection between the PC Visual Studio 2017 and the Mac. The .ssh directory was created automatically with the correct permissions, etc.

Failing that, try doing an `ssh` to your Mac from your PC using any one of the many ssh clients available for windows. It may give you an indication of what is preventing you from reaching the Mac.